# textViewShouldBeginEditing called continuously in ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using xcode 5 and ios7 simulator. In which textViewShouldBeginEditing called continuously, rather then once when textview becomes active.

Is there any solution to call textViewShouldBeginEditing method only once.

Thank you in advance for your help and consideration.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: This is just a problem of using the method - (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView

Comment: This is not typical behavior and is probably a result of your code, which is why it would be helpful to see the relevant portions.  What is your implementation of that method?

Comment: I have a questionnair in pagecontrolview where each question having comment button which shows a textview to allow any comment(text) for particular question. Initially the textview is blank. that's it

Comment: I got It. I was using [textview becomeFirstResponder]; within textViewShouldBeginEditing so that it is looping, Thanx for help and consideration once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[textview becomeFirstResponder];
method within textViewShouldBeginEditing will take looping.
It will work in iOS 6 but in iOS 7 need to remove.The responder will automatic to the corresponding textview.